# Discord.js If funtion issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this simple code here:

```js
let stars = args[0]
        if(stars === 0) {
            let starsEmoji = `0 stars`
        } else if(stars == 1) {
            let starsEmoji = `1 stars`
        } else if(stars == 2) {
            let starsEmoji = `2 stars`
        }else if(stars == 3) {
            let starsEmoji = `3 stars`
        }else if(stars == 4) {
            let starsEmoji = `4 stars`
        }else if(stars == 5) {
            let starsEmoji = `5 stars`
        }
```

what am trying to do here is to define starsEmoji when the arg[0] is equal to 0 to 5 but the issue is that it gives me error even when the arg[0] is a number when trying to use starsEmoji in another code line it gives me error `ReferenceError: starsEmoji is not defined`

I have at the start of the code

```js
if(isNaN(args[0])) return 
if(args[0] > 5) return
```

to make sure its a number, not quite sure what's wrong with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
let stars = args[0]
let starsEmoji

if (stars === 0) {
  starsEmoji = `0 stars`
} else if(stars == 1) {
  starsEmoji = `1 stars`
} else if(stars == 2) {
  starsEmoji = `2 stars`
}else if(stars == 3) {
  starsEmoji = `3 stars`
}else if(stars == 4) {
  starsEmoji = `4 stars`
}else if(stars == 5) {
  starsEmoji = `5 stars`
}
```

The `let` statement declares a block-scoped local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. If you define starsEmoji in the if block, your code outside of the block cannot access to `starsEmoji`, because it is not initialized outside of the block

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier solution to this, however first thing to check is to make sure `starsEmoji` is in the scope you plan to use it in. The easiest way to ensure this is to define it in the global scope.

Instead of doing `else if ... else if ... else if`, just use template literals to dynamically concatenate your string.

```
if(isNaN(args[0])) return 
if(args[0] > 5 || args[0] < 0) return

// Define Variable outside of any scope
let starsEmoji = '';

// Instead of stacking else-if's, use template literals
starsEmoji = `${args[0]} stars`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're getting, maybe starsEmoji is local to the "if" statement. Meaning, it can't be used outside. Try putting `let starsEmoji` before the if statement, get rid of all the "let"s inside, and try it out. Hope this helped :)

Comment: after putting that and using starsEmoji in another line it just appears as "undefined"

Comment: Ah, just copy/paste YoungChoi's solution. I think you still have "let" statements inside the "if" statements, that's why.